# Entity Fw 4, MVC3, Derived class does not appear in the ObjectContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I'm using MVC3 with EF (version 4, but not sure if 4.0,4.1,etc). I've been fighting with this since yesterday and I don't find the answer anywhere. I'm using the book "Pro Entity Framework 4.0".

I did Model First approach and because I want to use inheritance I created a basic model to do the first testings (sorry, click the link, I don't have enough rep to put a picture):

[EF Model](http://i39.tinypic.com/2i9108o.jpg)

Then with this model I created the database. I'm not very happy with the naming convention, because in spite of pluralizing the entity names, for the derived class table it created a prefixed-single table name. I'm sorry I don't have SSMS installed but have a look through the Server Explorer, see the picture:

[DB created from EF Model](http://i43.tinypic.com/11ag9sh.jpg)

Then I created controllers for BaseClass with the template "Controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework". It works great! It created all the views, CRUD.

For instance in the Details view I have this code:

```
//
    // GET: /BaseClass/Details/5

    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        BaseClass baseclass = db.BaseClasses.Single(b => b.Id == id);
        return View(baseclass);
    }
```

It works fine.

Then I did the same for the DerivedClass and I got the controller with all the CRUD actions and the views. And now the problem. For instance the Details controller of the DerivedClass is like this:

```
//
    // GET: /DerivedClass/Details/5

    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        DerivedClass derivedclass = db.BaseClasses.Single(d => d.Id == id);
        return View(derivedclass);
    }
```

As you can see it tries to get db.BaseClasses instead of db.DerivedClasses, with gives a compilation error, but db does not provide any access to the DerivedClass entity, there is nothing in db at all related with DerivedClass.But if I create manually an instance of DerivedClass in the code it is possible:

```
MyNamespace.Blablabla.Site.Models.DerivedClass dev = new Models.DerivedClass();
```

Am I missing anything? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance hierarchies are mapped to one DbSet. If you want to filter on inherited entities you can use:

```
  DerivedClass derivedclass = db.BaseClasses.OfType<DerivedClass>().Single(d => d.Id == id);
```

The [`OfType<>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344857.aspx) filters the object set for instances of the type you specify.

For adding and updating a derived entity you can also the parent DbSet and EF will map it to the correct tables.